# Assigning a value to specific product

Tags: expression-manipulation

I was wondering if there is a way to assign a value to a specific problem.

For example if I wanted $a\cdot a$ to equal $-1$. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Can you explain your particular use case through an example?  I could suggest several "solutions" which would seem to fit what you are asking but I suspect that most of them won't be useful to you.

Comment: Please include some code for your example, or at least a greater explanation.  Possibly `UpSet` or `TagSet` will be applicable but I cannot yet tell.  What is $a$?

Comment: I am dealing with multiplication of the elements in the Hamiltonians. so things of the form a+bi+cj+dk.

Comment: so `i*i=-1`, or `i*j=k` and so on

Comment: Quaternions are already built-in to Mathematica; see `Quaternions/tutorial/Quaternions` in the Documentation Center to learn how to use them.

Comment: It is still not clear to me.  Is $a$ or `$i$` a Symbol or numeric?  We need some *specific* examples still.

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Good catch.

Comment: "Assign a value to a specific problem"?  What does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

If all you are looking for is a basic implementation of quaternions, then there is no need to implement them yourself, since they are already built-in:

```
<< Quaternions`
Quaternion[0, 1, 0, 0] ** Quaternion[0, 1, 0, 0]
```

producing

```
Quaternion[-1, 0, 0, 0]
```

as you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to interpret your question. You seem to be asking about defining an *operation*. Let's call it "dot". If you want dot of any pair to be -1, then you specify:

```
dot[a_, a_] := -1
```

Now you have the property that whenever you type something like `dot[w,w]` or `dot[5,5]` you get -1 but dot takes on no value for things like `dot[a]` or `dot[a,b]`. Of course you could define these other cases as well to build up a complete operation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking for [TagSet](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSet.html), see also [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users).

```
a /: a*a = -1
```

> `-1`

```
list = Range[1, 10]
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

```
a a + list
```

> `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}`

```
a a*list
```

> `{-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10}`

```
ca = ConstantArray[a a, {2, 2}]
```

> `{{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}`

```
ca*a a
```

> `{{1, 1}, {1, 1}}`

```
mat = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} + a a
```

> `{{0, 1}, {2, 3}}`